# What's the reading order for X-Men Second Coming?

Tags: comics, marvel, suggested-order

I'm a bit confused with this story arc. The chapters are clearly defined on the cover but I'm unsure where X-factor/Hellbound/Blind Science comes into the picture as they are part of "Second Coming: Revelations" and doesn't seemed to be directly tied to the main "Second Coming" arc.

Can someone please enlighten me? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is a bit convoluted (though, that is par for the X-Men Books).**

[image]  [image]

**[Release Order](http://www.uncannyxmen.net/db/crossover/showquestion.asp?fldAuto=241)** - taken, mostly, from the [official checklist](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YVb3G7RiPcc/S2ojQtgwPaI/AAAAAAAACis/9KWWIGny4vk/s400/Second%20Coming%20Flyer%202.jpg)**:**

- **00 - X-MEN: HOPE #1** [Collects the 3-part "A Girl Called Hope" back-story of Hope Summers originally printed in Psylocke mini-series #1, Dark X-Men mini-series #1 & X-Men Legacy #230 as well as adds a final chapter to that story.]
- **00 - X-Men: Second Coming: Prepare** [Takes place two days after Hope & Cable return from the future placing it chronologically after X-Force (3rd series) #26.]
- 01 - X-Men: Second Coming #1
- 02 - Uncanny X-Men #523
- 03 - New Mutants (3rd series) #12
- 04 - X-Men Legacy #235
- 05 - X-Force (3rd series) #26
- **Parallel to main plot - Second Coming – Revelations: X-Factor (1st series) #204**
- 06 - Uncanny X-Men #524
- 07 - New Mutants (3rd series) #13
- 08 X-Men Legacy #236
- 09 - X-Force (3rd series) #27
- **Parallel to main plot - Second Coming – Revelations: X-Factor (1st series) #205**
- **Parallel to main plot - X-Men: Second Coming – Revelations: Hellbound #1** [Chronologically taking place shortly after the events in Uncanny X-Men #524]

[image]

- **Interlude X-Men: Second Coming – Revelations: Blind Science #1** [Originally solicited under the subtitle CLASSIFIED.  The story is continued in X-Men: Legacy #236.]
- 10 - Uncanny X-Men #525
- 11 - New Mutants (3rd series) #14
- 12 - X-Men Legacy #237
- 13 - X-Force (3rd series) #28
- **Parallel to main plot - Second Coming – Revelations: X-Factor (1st series) #206**
- **Parallel to main plot - X-Men: Second Coming – Revelations: Hellbound #2**
- 14 - X-Men: Second Coming #2
- **Parallel to main plot - X-Men: Second Coming – Revelations: Hellbound #3**

[image] [image] [image]

*I also found a **[Reading Order Card](http://xmenchecklist.blogspot.com/2010/03/x-men-second-coming-reading-map.html)** for you that might help clear things up just a bit:*

[image]

Comment: Less a reading order, more a chronology for purists but an excellent find nonetheless.

Comment: well both really... it's in release order but the chronology is noted where need apply.

Answer (score 1):

Per the reviews on [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8678704-x-men), the consensus of opinion seems to be that the stories in "**X-Men: Second Coming - Revelations**" are best seen as 'side stories' that loosely relate to the main comic series but without adding much in the way of exposition. It should be read *after* having read [X-Men : Second Coming.](http://marvel.wikia.com/Second_Coming)

Respected Goodreads librarian Xavier Guillaume said;

> I borrowed **X-Men: Second Coming Revelations** from the library thinking
>   it was the follow up of X-Men: Second Coming and it would
>   shed more life on Hope's story-arc, but reading it, it felt more like
>   watching deleted scenes on a DVD/Blu-ray disc. For some reason deleted
>   scenes feel like a good idea to watch, but afterwards, all I can think
>   is, "*Oh okay...That's why they cut that from the show...*"